# how to pass parameter to get and post methods retrofit

Tags: android

Hello guys i'm implementing an android rest client using retrofit library.I also implemented an API (using laravel framework) .so i call the API(GET method) with parameters unfortunately it's not working..

this is my post method url `"http://androidxxxxx-xx/api/OneUser/Id"`

when i test this url in postman its working properly 
eg : `"http://androidxxxxx-xx/api/OneUser/001"`

here is my Inferface class code:

public interface OneUserApi {

```
//oneUser
@GET("/api/OneUser/{UserId}")
Call<OneUserDetails> GetAllUserDetailss(@Path("UserId")String id);
//  Call<AllUserDetails> GetAllUserDetailss();
```

}

This is my buttoneven code

```
  oneuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String UserId="001";


            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Api_Url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();


            OneUserApi service = retrofit.create(OneUserApi.class);
            Call<OneUserDetails> call = service.GetAllUserDetailss("001");
            Log.d("onResponse", "There is uuyan error");
            call.enqueue(new Callback<OneUserDetails>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<OneUserDetails> call, retrofit2.Response<OneUserDetails> response) {


                    try {
                        Log.d("onResponse", "There rtutrutris an error");
                      //  one_UserId = response.body().
                        // int clientId=response.body().getUserId();
                      String UserId,TokenType,ExpierTime,AccessToken,Create,Update;
                        //  clientSecret = response.body().getAcessToken();
                        // Log.e("ss", clientSecret);
                        //  String clientSecret;
                   //     Log.d("onResponse", "There is anccccc error");
                    //    for (int i = 0; i < one_UserId.size(); i++) {

                            UserId = response.body().getUserId();
                            TokenType = response.body().getTokenType();
                            ExpierTime = response.body().getAcessToken();
                            AccessToken =response.body().getExpiertime();
                            Create = response.body().getUpdatedAt();
                            Update =response.body().getCreatedAt();

                            Log.e("UserId", UserId);
                            Log.e("TokenType", TokenType);
                            Log.e("ExpierTime", ExpierTime);
                            Log.e("AccessToken", AccessToken);
                            Log.e("Create", Create);
                            Log.e("Update", Update);




                     //   }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<OneUserDetails> call, Throwable t) {
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

my json data when passing this url in postman 
("http://androidxxxxx-xx/api/OneUser/001")

```
{
"UserId": "001",
"TokenType": "dffdfdfd",
"Expiertime": "dffdfddf4",
"AcessToken": "fdljfhjdlnfdf",
"created_at": "2017-07-13 03:18:51",
"updated_at": "2017-07-13 03:18:51"
```

}
]

myOneUserDetails.java clas

```
public class OneUserDetails implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("UserId")
@Expose
private String userId;
@SerializedName("TokenType")
@Expose
private String tokenType;
@SerializedName("Expiertime")
@Expose
private String expiertime;
@SerializedName("AcessToken")
@Expose
private String acessToken;
@SerializedName("created_at")
@Expose
private String createdAt;
@SerializedName("updated_at")
@Expose
private String updatedAt;

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getTokenType() {
    return tokenType;
}

public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
    this.tokenType = tokenType;
}

public String getExpiertime() {
    return expiertime;
}

public void setExpiertime(String expiertime) {
    this.expiertime = expiertime;
}

public String getAcessToken() {
    return acessToken;
}

public void setAcessToken(String acessToken) {
    this.acessToken = acessToken;
}

public String getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public String getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide stack trace and full code?

Comment: i update my answer @Tim

Comment: Did you try to update your `interface AllUserApi` from answers? You should edit @GET cause there is error in relative URL.

Comment: it's a laravel URL error?...not a error in android codes?

Comment: but when is test this URL using postman.it's work properly...(http://androidxxxxx-xx.com/api/OneUser/001)

Comment: nope, it's error in your code

Comment: your JSON ends with `}]`? Is response has an array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the id as a parameter by adding the {id} to your GET Request

```
    @GET("api/OneUser/{id}")
```

Comment: yah i update get method..but still  no data are retrieve from the Api  @GET("/api/OneUser/{id}")
    Call<AllUserDetails>GetAllUserDetailss(@Path("id")String UserInfo);

Comment: @ChmathKalubovila it's not an error, just empty response? Could you show the response from postman and `AllUserDetails` class.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Show us your log or whatever the error you are getting so that we can help

Comment: @Fatifati no any error displaying on the log file..... that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

It's all in RetroFit introduction http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
@GET("api/OneUser/{id}")
Call<AllUserDetails>GetAllUserDetails(@Path("id")String UserInfo);
```